# How to Remove duplicate from array in js using set and put each item in li tag ....below is my code

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```js
const xx = [" 4", "9", "16"," 4", "9", "16"," 4", "9", "16"]

<ul> {(<li> {[...new Set(xx)]} </li>)} </ul>
```

const xx = [" 4", "9", "16"," 4", "9", "16"," 4", "9", "16"]

  {(
- {[...new Set(xx)]}
  )}

Answer (score 0):

Here, this would work fine

```js
const xx = [" 4", "9", "16"," 4", "9", "16"," 4", "9", "16"];
const set = [...new Set(xx)];
let html = '';
set.forEach(el => {
    html += `<li>${el}</li>`;
});

document.querySelector("#list").insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

You could also do the same with the array methods

```js
const xx = [" 4", "9", "16"," 4", "9", "16"," 4", "9", "16"];
const html = [...new Set(xx)].map(el => `<li>${el}</li>`).join('');
document.querySelector("#list").insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: `li` elements are not valid children of a `div` unless their parent is a valid list